# Error when Run the Sample Code to Assistant from Google SDK to RaspberryPi 3

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, google-assistant-sdk

i create the step by step tutorial from Google SSK site to RaspberryPi 3 but when i try to run the

> googlesamples-assistant-hotword --project-id my-dev-project
>   --device-model-id my-model

e have this errors:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "/home/pi/env/bin/googlesamples-assistant-hotword", line 11, in 
>   sys.exit(main()) File
>   "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/googlesamples/assistant/library/hotword.py",
>   line 139, in main device_model_id, device_id, args.nickname) File
>   "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/assistant/library/device_helpers.py",
>   line 88, in register_device raise RegistrationError(r,
>   device_model_id)
>   google.assistant.library.device_helpers.RegistrationError: Failed to
>   register device INVALID_ARGUMENT (400): Could not get the device
>   instance. Project_id from side channel and project_id from url do not
>   match.

Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: Are you actually using `my-dev-project` or replacing that with your project id?

Comment: :) Replacing with my project ID

Comment: Is that the same project that your `credentials.json` uses?